# foreach isn't working correctly with simple xml

Tags: php, xml

Not sure why but the mailer keeps telling me I dont have an email in there, i know im just accessing it incorrectly

XML file:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schools>
    <schoolData>
        <name>Dude</name>
        <schoolName>NA</schoolName>
        <email>sls@gmail.com</email>
        <mascot>Da bears</mascot>
    </schoolData>
    <schoolData>
        <name>Dude2</name>
        <schoolName>gg</schoolName>
        <email>sl3@gmail.com</email>
        <mascot>Muffin</mascot>
    </schoolData>
    <schoolData>
        <name>Dude3</name>
        <schoolName>123</schoolName>
        <email>s1@gmail.com</email>
        <mascot>cheesecakeface</mascot>
    </schoolData>
    <schoolData>
        <name>Dude234</name>
        <schoolName>456</schoolName>
        <email>1@gmail.com</email>
        <mascot>Bob</mascot>
    </schoolData>
</schools>
```

`

```
    <?php
$XML = simplexml_load_file('http://domain/hMail/data/list.xml');

foreach ($XML as $school) {
    $mail->AltBody = 'Come see me play Tonight!';
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
    $mail->addAddress($school->schoolData->email);
}
```

`

`
I've also tried $XML->schoolData / $school->email

Comment: It has to be `$school->email`. Not regarding to your question, but setting property `AltBody` and calling method `msgHTML` should be out of the loop.

Comment: AltBody yea, but contents html requires stuff from inside the xml

Comment: You should check if `simplexml_load_file` function has loaded XML file correctly. Just call `print_r($XML)` and see the output.

Comment: The answer above was right, i dont know why it is that way - kind of confusing, but makes sense since its 'simple'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just works despite what has been said in the question.

Comment: If you feel confused about the magic that ships with SimpleXML, it's often a good idea to work through http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic again with a pot of coffee. It clarifies most standard usages of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $school->email works.  Tested with this code - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fxz-1k6